# What does "Session doesn't have required client" mean?

Tags: keycloak

I have a question concerning Keycloak 4.8.3.

I am using the spring security adapter to secure our web-app with the keycloak and the enabled login feature: remember-me.

The user logs in from a browser and it redirects back to out web app.

Our web-app then calls another Keycloak secured REST-API endpoint internally using the KeycloakRestTemplate, because we need to authorize these calls as well using the same user of the web app.

The point is: I want to use the authorization token for another REST-API service method.

After some amount of time the REST-API call fails with the following error message:

```
ERROR RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext Refresh token failure status: 400 {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Session doesn't have required client"}
```

and the keycloak log file contains the folowing warning:

```
17:25:51,929 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-1) type=REFRESH_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=EHotel, clientId=IBE, userId=f:8db533c4-9733-48d4-8b30-28a50954b7ad:khaendel, ipAddress=192.168.1.76, error=invalid_token, grant_type=refresh_token, refresh_token_type=Refresh, refresh_token_id=9fba841f-54bb-4c81-8f7b-6a7e1c5ab92e, client_auth_method=client-secret
```

I cannot predict when exactly that happens, presumably after 15 minutes or after an hour. Token expiration is set as follows:
SSO Session Idle: 15 minutes
SSO Session Max: 15 minutes
SSO Session Idle Remember Me: 1 Day
SSO Session Max Remember Me: 1 Day
Access Token Lifespan: 5 minutes

What does the error message (Session doesn't have required client) mean and

what am i doing wrong?

Remote debugging revealed:
It seems, that at the keycloak server is a client session cache involved (InfinispanUserSessionProvider), that looses information after a while.

I expected to use the keycloak token authenticate another REST-API service with the same user as our secured web-app. But the refresh token cannot be used as long as the SSO session because of the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Keycloak developer team has confirmed, that this is a bug in the current version of keycloak 4.8.3.
Client sessions must be valid during the longer remember-me session.
This bug will be fixed in the next version. Jira Ticket is for the time of writing not available.

Comment: Do you happen to know which version fixes this issue? That would be extremely helpful :)

Comment: My Correction was:
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/model/infinispan/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/sessions/infinispan/InfinispanUserSessionProvider.java
Line 532:
`.filter(AuthenticatedClientSessionPredicate.create(realm.getId()).expired(expiredRememberMe))`
instead of 
`.filter(AuthenticatedClientSessionPredicate.create(realm.getId()).expired(Math.min(expired, expiredRememberMe)))`
This has been corrected wrong in 5.0 :-(

Comment: I got exactly the same issue with the latest version of Keycloak (18.x.x), so if it is a bug, it is not yet fixed.